# Fade images after delay

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I'm trying to switch images in a div every few seconds 
the current code works, but there are 2 things that I want to change and I need your help for that:

1. The div resizes to the current image displaying in it, I want it to always use the size of the bigger image
2. I want to fade between the images instead of just switching

Thanks for reading, I hope you can help me.

This is what I got so far:

```js
var imgIndex = 0;
setInterval(function() {
  images[imgIndex].style.display = "none";
  imgIndex++;
  if (imgIndex >= images.length) {
    imgIndex = 0;
  }
  images[imgIndex].style.display = "block";
}, 5000);
```

```css
.imageDisplay {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  background-Color: white;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 5%;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 1px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

.imageDisplay:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.Image {
  width: 99%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 1px;
  padding: 1px;
  border-radius: 5%;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="imageDisplay">
  <p>Description</p>
  <img class="Image"></img>
  <img class="Image"></img>
</div>
```

Comment: you can't set the size of bigger image automatically

Comment: _“I want it to always use the size of the bigger image”_ - if you want that to happen automatically, no matter what actual images are used, you need to pre-load them, so that you can read their dimensions afterwards. That is something you can go research. _“I want to fade between the images instead of just switching”_ - also something you please go properly research first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you could set the div to be equal to the size of the large image and then use:

```
object-fit: cover;
object-position:center;
```

As for switching you could use:

```
transition: opacity .3s linear;
```

Read here on how to exactly implement the transitions. My suggestion would be stacking them all up and fading them in one by one every few seconds.

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp

http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm trying to set the height of the div with div.style.height = div.getBoundingClientRect().height; while having the biggest image displayed, but now all divs are either too big or too small for their images.

Comment: using css object-fit: cover; should tell the images to fill the divs space in all dimensions without distoring the images

Comment: I made some progress, now using the visibility instead of display property, and also changed a bit in css, but don't have the changed code rn. the divs are now not wrapping their content anymore, just the description text at the top, the rest overflows

Comment: I got the resizing to work now using div.style.height = div.scrollHeight;